# How to fix broken hinge (side part of it) of acer aspire e15

Tags: laptop, hardware-failure, laptop-repair

How to fix this broken laptop hinge? Can I glue the broken hinge parts?
[Image of the broken hinge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMmRT.jpg)

Comment: Either JB-Weld [SteelStick](https://www.jbweld.com/product/steelstik-epoxy-putty-stick) or [Steel Epoxy](https://www.jbweld.com/product/j-b-weld-syringe); for the latter, you'll want to also get static mixer syringe tips, either [JB-Weld's](https://www.jbweld.com/product/static-mixers) or [generic](https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07T72C2TB) ones

Answer (score 0):

To the 90+ % level, no.  The torque on the lid will break any glue joint on the metal hinge. The torque is surprising high.

You need to replace the hinge (if you can get the part) or see if a lid comes with hinges (eBay).

I have done this (ThinkPad T61) and had a local repair shop get the hinge and replace it.

Friction on a laptop hinge is high (to make the lid stay put when open). This is what (a) makes the high torque and (b) what breaks a metal hinge if it seizes.

Chances of repair is really low.

Answer (score 0):

If the hinges are metal and you can take apart the entire case to get to them, just weld the hinge together with the broken metal part on the other side. Sand down the part that bulges out.

However, parts are usually a couple of bucks on online auction sites, so self repair is useful only if you are isolated or require a quick fix.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem with my acer laptop. The easiest/cheapest solution I found was to use a money clip to hold the case together. Works like surprisingly well for a $2 solution.

Comment: Don't know why I'm getting downvoted. Every solution to this acer e15 hinge issue I found was either costly or complicated. Just trying to save people $$ and effort. But sure, go replace the hinge or take apart the case and start welding if you want.